# Как заставить группу setInterval работать синхронно?

Tags: javascript

```
 this.fade = function (t, f){
    var t = t || 500;
    var f = f || 50;
    var steps = t / (1000 / f);   
    var op = 1;
    var d0 = 1 / steps;
    this.elements.forEach((e)=>{var timer = setInterval(function(){
        var current = timer;
        op -= d0;
        // устанавливаем opacity элементу DOM
        e.style.opacity = op;
        // уменьшаем количество оставшихся шагов анимации
        steps--;

        // если анимация окончена
        if(e.style.opacity <= 0){
        // убираем интервал выполнения
            clearInterval(current);
            // и убираем элемент из потока документа
            e.style.display = 'none';
        }

    }, 1000)});

};
```

код аналогичен fade jquery, только вот работает асинхронно(элементы исчезают не одновременно). Как задать setInterval чтобы они все работали синхронно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
this.fade = function (t, f){
    var t = t || 500;
    var f = f || 50;
    var steps = t / (1000 / f);   
    var op = 1;
    var d0 = 1 / steps;

    var timer = setInterval(() => {
        op -= d0;

        this.elements.forEach((element) => {
            e.style.opacity = op;

            if(op <= 0){
                clearInterval(timer);
                e.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
};
```